# Password complexity, restrictions on self-answering, and pop-up help all contributed to a frustrating experience for me as a new user

Tags: discussion, feedback, user-experience

Well, this is the feedback section, so here's my feedback.

I wanted to ask a question on Stack Overflow, so I went through the whole registration process, and eventually got the answer I was looking for.

I hit a few bumps that negatively impacted my user experience.

- Password complexity. I'm using a Stack Exchange account, so I understand that's not directly related to this site, but it was what I used. I shouldn't need a complex password to ask a question.
- Answering my own question. I got the answer I was looking for about three hours after I posted the question. When I went to answer my own question for the benefit of everyone else, I was told I would have to wait a few hours because I was a new user and wasn't allowed. I found that to be silly and not worth my time.
- All of the popup help along the way was very annoying, especially when it caused the content of the page to move around. I would prefer the option to ask for help rather than having it shoved in my face.
- Clicking twice to log out? Bad usability.
- Asking if I'm human when I'm logged in? Really? Aren't we past that once I'm registered and all that?

That was my user experience. Now you have your feedback. Hope it helps in some way.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40925/do-not-ask-for-confirmation-on-logout http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110905/please-tone-the-captchas-back-down http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97425/reduce-accepting-own-answer-delay http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110678/can-stack-overflow-change-the-password-criteria

Comment: Ask for help how? And in what context?

Comment: All of these except the popup help have already been discussed elsewhere (I'm not aware of a popup discussion at least). It's nice that he's providing feedback, but I don't see how recreating a bunch of discussions all in one question is constructive for Meta.

Comment: You may want to ask the `popup-help` and `clicking twice to log out` questions separately (though it seems the logout one is covered, and   FWIW I think the clicking twice to log out is a usability *win*: It prevents me from accidentally bumping the logout link and having to do the OpenID dance.)

Comment: One suggestion I have (likely already discussed) is to have a form to submit feedback rather than making a "question" out of it. That might have made this whole thing smoother. Just my opinion. Sorry for trouble it may have caused, and hope it helped.

Comment: As a developer on the Q&A team I can assure you this does help and that we do take such feedback seriously. Our product manager certainly has some ideas about improving many of these.

Comment: @JeffV The Q&A format for feedback is a mixed bag -- it works pretty well most of the time, it just completely falls apart for multiple-issue posts (especially if many of the issues have already been discussed) :-/

Comment: The most important part of the Q&A format for feedback is it keeps everything familiar. There's hardly any "second system" to learn to submit or respond to feedback. None of that uservoice crap

Comment: RE the password criteria: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110678/can-stack-overflow-change-the-password-criteria

Comment: @jeffV, thanks. User experience is one of our primary foci right now, particularly for *new* users. Your feedback is very helpful, and for the most part on point.

Answer (score 9):

> Password complexity. I'm using a Stack Exchange account, so I
>   understand that's not directly related to this site, but it was what I
>   used. I shouldn't need a complex password to ask a question.

True, but it might be handy to make it difficult for someone to hack your account and do bad things with it on your behalf, especially if you're going to be here for awhile and reputation becomes (relatively) important to you.

> All of the popup help along the way was very annoying, especially when
>   it caused the content of the page to move around. I would prefer the
>   option to ask for help rather than having it shoved in my face.

This may be due to the fact that many people don't read the instructions when they first use an SE site.  Popups are a little harder to ignore.  You sound like you probably don't need them, but many other people might.

> Asking if I'm human when I'm logged in? Really? Aren't we past that
>   once I'm registered and all that?

The presence of Captcha's is usually due to rate limiting of some sort.  Bots can still use registered accounts, and we don't really want to grant them any special favors just because their owner registered an account.   This is especially true of new users.

> Clicking twice to log out? Bad usability.

Interesting observation.  In the three or so years I've used SE, I've only felt compelled to log out maybe two or three times, so the dual-click aspect never really bothered me.