# United Login for Stack Exchange sites which a Person has Signed Up

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts, openid

I am wondering why a user who has SE accounts in several sites has to login to each site separately?

I understand the logic behind not creating a SE account on all SE sites and having separate sign-up procedure for each site.

But why am I required to login separately (or as is the case, I get logged in after I open a site and then asked to refresh page) into each page?

I also understand that one person may have different accounts across the SE sites.

What I am asking is why not login one account of a person into all the sites in which (s)he is a member of using that account?

This is not about
1. Signing up (at all)
2. Feature-request (maybe changed depending on answer)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/

Comment: And looks like this all might change in the future: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246689/new-year-new-experiment-login-and-signup-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am asking is why not login one account of a person into all the sites in which (s)he is a member of using that account?

Because that's how it was implemented back in ... 2010? Some years ago. Each site has its own database and network-wide features have been evolving over time as the network grows.

We know it's a crappy and error-prone experience, and we are working on a more seamless login system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How will the new login system in beta work?

Comment: @CRags We're still working out some of the details, but the goal is basically what you're asking for - logging in on one Q&A site will log you in network-wide. We'll be publishing a blog and/or meta posts with the gory details when the time comes.

Comment: Great, thanks for the hard work