# Isn't the updated login screens a step backwards in terms of usability?

Tags: feature-request, login, auto-login

I'm a regular visitor to stackoverflow, serverfault and superuser, and up until today, logging into all three took far less steps.

Before I could go to stackoverflow, hit login, choose log in with Google. Then go to serverfault, hit login and it would say "you have been logged in, redirecting...". Then repeat for superuser.

Today, I have to choose my login method/account on all three sites. Seems like a step backwards to me.

I liked the old functionality more - as a user who does not keep cookies between browser sessions and logs in each day, and as a user with two Google accounts which means the login with Google process has an additional step.

As a side note, it seems meta.stackexchange.com still preserves the old functionality with automatically detecting that I was logged in at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Shouldn't be related to the [experiment we're running](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246689/new-year-new-experiment-login-and-signup-ui). None of the backend auth code has changed, only the UI. I've been trying to keep an eye on this, but for the life of me I can't reproduce global auth failing on my end. Gonna continue keeping an eye on it, but... replacing the current login system with a more robust [universal login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246771/155160) may happen first either way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Hmm.. seems I should retract my question, the behaviour I explained above was indeed happening half an hour ago, but now I cannot reproduce it. I now got the "Welcome back davur. you are logged in..." message. I am using Chrome 37 on OSX Yosemite.

Comment: The updated login UI made me think it was a programmed in change in behaviour too.